# How do I unlock the Sinestar ship in Deep Loot?

Tags: deep-loot

How do I unlock the **Sinestar** ship in the mobile game *Deep Loot*? Most ships can be purchased with coins, but the Sinestar has a lock symbol and an "Unlock?" button. When the button is pressed a hint pops up that says "Search amongst the mines...".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unlock the **Sinestar** by finding the crashed "*G-SALV*" spaceship. It is located in the grey stone region at about 150 meters depth. This region has a lot of [naval mines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_mine), which explains the hint "search amongst the mines".

Since levels are randomly generated each time you dive, the best way to find it is to go to the correct depth and swim to one side until you locate the ship or run out of air and have to start over. Using a *super boost* will immediately lower you to 120 meters, which means you will only have to swim down a few more meters to get to the correct depth and hence will have more time to search for the crashed ship.

#### The crashed ship

This is what the crashed ship looks like.

[image: The area with the G-SALV spaceship that unlocks the Sinestar]

#### The unlock message

Once you reach the area a message will pop up indicating that the ship has been unlocked.

[image: Reward screen for the Sinestar]